# Error resurce compiling

Tags: visual-studio, resources, visual-studio-6

I have problem. I add new dialog in old project, and I have some error:

```
X:MEATFACTORYMaterialsMaterials.rc (22): error RC2135 : file not found: 0x19
X:MEATFACTORYMaterialsMaterials.rc (74): error RC2135 : file not found: 128
X:MEATFACTORYMaterialsMaterials.rc (1764): error RC2104 : undefined keyword or key name: IDC_LIST_RESULT
Error executing rc.exe.
```

What is it means? 
codepage in file  - win1251
what do me?
I need resolve this problem only for VC6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At all, the cause of this error was that in the process of adding resources VS6.0 then why (why ? This is not understood) has created another new file resourse.h in the expansion which was added two do not read Unicode characters. That is, were present in the directory two files resourse.h - and with different content. When I set up the conditions as compile / c 68001 - then picked up by a file with Unicode but not complete - and that caused a second group of errors. And if the file is compiled as ASCII - from the point of view of the file system at the studio had two files with the same name - and not one of them could not read ( of course). That is, if you get this error - check the file resource.h - and places without glitches such as in this case .
It is also (probably) this is due to the fact that VS works for me on virtualke to Linux - but from the point of view of the file system of Linux is nothing extraordinary - just two files with different names.